# Listening to a microphone while running a GUI in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a GUI that displays the text spoken into the microphone on Python but was wondering if there was any way of doing this. From what I've seen, I haven't been able to run code while Tkinter was up. When I run the program, the block that runs the voice recognition doesn't run until the GUI is closed. Sorry English is not my first language :)

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: post the program

Comment: Tkinter displays the UI using a loop, so if we call some function from Tkinter it will freeze till that function stops running. This will be especially visible when the function being called has a loop inside. One of the solutions for this is to use a multithread call using the `threading` module in python.